# Find locus of all points that its sum of squares of distance between them and point $A(x_A,y_A)$ and $B(x_B,y_B)$ equals to $k$.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, locus

> Find locus of all points that its sum of squares of distance between them and point $A(x_A,y_A)$ and $B(x_B,y_B)$ equals to $k$.

We know that all the points that their sum of distances between them and two points are equal to $k$, form an oval. But this question is about sum of "square of distances", not sum of distances.
Equation of all points in this locus is :
$(x-x_A)^2 + (y-y_A)^2 + (x-x_B)^2 + (y-y_B)^2 = k$

 I replaced $x_A,y_A,x_B$ and $y_B$ and $k$ with numbers and drew the graph, and noticed that it is still an oval! Why does this happen? And how to calculate the center of this? 
Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Hint:  expand and combine like terms, then complete the squares.  Should get an ellipse in standard form.

Comment: thanks. I don't know much about ellipses. you mean ax^2 + bx^2 = r^2 ? and how is it possible to find centers of this ellipse in terms of xA,xB,yA,yB and k ?

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) is a general discussion about ellipses and how to write them in coordinate systems.

Comment: @madfdadfd, it is a circle and its center is the midpoint of the segment $AB$, moreover the length of diameter is $\sqrt{2k-\overline{AB}^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of all points of this locus is :

$(x-x_A)^2+(y-y_A)^2+(x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2=k\;\;,$

$2x^2\!+\!2y^2\!-\!2(x_A\!+\!x_B)x\!-\!2(y_A\!+\!y_B)y\!+\!x_A^2\!+\!y_A^2\!+\!x_B^2\!+\!y_B^2\!=\!k\;,$

$x^2\!+\!y^2\!-\!(x_A\!+\!x_B)x\!-\!(y_A\!+\!y_B)y\!+\dfrac{x_A^2\!+\!y_A^2\!+\!x_B^2\!+\!y_B^2\!-\!k}2=0\;.$

It is a circle and its center is the point $\,C\left(\dfrac{x_A\!+\!x_B}2,\dfrac{y_A\!+\!y_B}2\right)$ which is the midpoint of the segment $AB$.

Moreover the length of radius is :

$\begin{align}r&=\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{x_A\!+\!x_B}2\right)^2\!+\left(\dfrac{y_A\!+\!y_B}2\right)^2\!-\dfrac{x_A^2\!+\!y_A^2\!+\!x_B^2\!+\!y_B^2\!-\!k}2}=\\[3pt]&=\sqrt{\dfrac{2x_Ax_B+2y_Ay_B-x_A^2-x_B^2-y_A^2-y_B^2+2k}4}=\\[3pt]&=\sqrt{\dfrac{2k-\left(x_A-x_B\right)^2-\left(y_A-y_B\right)^2}4}=\sqrt{\dfrac{2k-\overline{AB}^2}4}=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac12\sqrt{2k-\overline{AB}^2}\;.\end{align}$

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done with Cosine Rule as follows:

[image]

In the figure, $M$ is the mid-point of $AB$. Applying cosine rule on $\Delta MPB$,

$$a^2=d^2+\left( \frac{c}{2} \right)^2-2d\left( \frac{c}{2} \right)\cos \alpha   \tag{1}$$

Applying cosine rule on $\Delta MPA$

$$b^2 =d^2+\left( \frac{c}{2} \right)^2-2d\left( \frac{c}{2} \right)\cos \left(\pi - \alpha \right) $$

$$b^2 = d^2+\left( \frac{c}{2} \right)^2+2d\left( \frac{c}{2} \right)\cos \left(\alpha \right)   \tag{2}$$

$\because a^2+b^2=k$,

$(1)+(2) \implies$
$$a^2+b^2=2d^2+\frac{c^2}{2}$$

$$d=\frac{\sqrt{2k-c^2}}{2}$$

Since $d=\frac{\sqrt{2k-c^2}}{2}$ is a constant, the locus of $P$ is a circle centered at the mid-point $M$ of $AB$ and has radius $d=\frac{\sqrt{2k-c^2}}{2}.$

Comment: wow! This is really interesting

Comment: But I don't get one thing. if the lotus forms a circle and p is located on that, P angle should equal to 90 degree because AB is diameter of circle, which means a^2 + b^2 =k should equal to AB^2 , which certainly doesn't.

Comment: @madfdadfd, $M$ is the mid-point of $AB$ does not mean that $AB$ is the diameter of the circle. $AB$ is the diameter only when $k=c^2$.

Comment: yeah you're right. AB is not the diameter

Answer (score 0):

For sake of matching dimension let $k=c^2$ and consider two foci $(\pm a ,0).$ We have

$$ (x-a)^2+y^2 +(x+a)^2+y^2 =c^2 \to x^2+y^2=c^2/2-a^2 $$

which is the equation of a *circle* of radius

$$\sqrt{c^2/2-a^2}=\sqrt{k/2-a^2}$$

centered at the origin. For a real circle locus to exist the given $k$ should be

$$ k>\sqrt 2 a. $$